# Pick up the server name from a Yml file in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a ansible hosts file with the format:

```
all:
  children:
    app_servers:
      hosts:
        server1:
        server2:
        ...
```

I want to pick up all the server names from the hosts file. Here is my code:

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:  

    - include_vars:
        file: "~/code/devops/google/ansible/ansible-root/hosts"

    - set_fact:
        dev_hosts: "{{ all.children.app_servers.hosts }}"

    - debug: msg="{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ dev_hosts }}"
```

I got this error output:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 01 March 2023  17:42:36 +0000 (0:00:00.027)       0:00:01.075 ******* 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: {'server1': None, 'server2': None, ...}. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}
```

I have no idea how to use `wantlist=True` as it mentioned in the message. All I want is to pick up the server name from the hosts file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`inventory_hostnames`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/inventory_hostnames_lookup.html) lookup plugin to gather this info.

```yaml
- name: show all the hosts
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_inventory_hostnames:
    - all
```